# VBA macro to open Outlook 2016 message as "Editable"

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba

I'd like to be able click a QAT shortcut to run a macro which opens the current Outlook message in editable mode. And inserts the text "[Edited]" so I can see it has been.

I had a solution for Outlook 2013 (or possibly 2010) which no longer works:

```
Sub OpenForEditing()
    Dim olkMessage As Outlook.MailItem, _
        ofcCB As Object, _
        ofcCBB As Object, _
        olkInsp As Outlook.Inspector
    Set olkMessage = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
    olkMessage.Display
    Set olkInsp = Application.ActiveInspector
    Set ofcCB = olkInsp.CommandBars("Edit")
    Set ofcCBB = ofcCB.Controls("Edit Message")
    ofcCBB.Execute
    Set ofcCBB = Nothing
    Set ofcCB = Nothing
    Set olkMessage = Nothing
End Sub
```

Sue Mosher's solution at http://www.outlookcode.com/threads.aspx?forumid=3&messageid=31310 also seems kaput (for me). This might be because of CommandBars changes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this in Outlook 2010-2019/365:

```
Sub OpenForEditing()
    ActiveExplorer.Selection(1).Display
    ActiveInspector.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "EditMessage"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd been wrestling with getting the correct inspector for a PostItem I was creating and it'd been driving me nuts.